# Alarm Manager runs on specific time of the day

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager

I want to start this service at a specific time of the day but it wont respond. Any reasons for why that happens?

```
String time = sharedPrefs.getString("change_time", "");
    String[] parts = time.split(":");
    int chosenHour = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
    int chosenMinute = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, chosenHour);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, chosenMinute);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    Intent i = new Intent(this, SmsService.class);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, i, 0);
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 86400000, pIntent);
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
```

Answer (score 0):

Where do you put the code? Is that inside a `Service` (as I see the `super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)`? If yes, did you start your service?

For scheduling `AlarmManager`, I'd recommend to put the code in the `Application#onCreate()`.

Comment: Service.StartService()? and where do i put it?

Comment: Yes, that's the API. "Where do I put it?" => Depending on your need, e.g. if you want to start your service immediately, put it in `Application#onCreate()`, or you want to trigger it based on some event/action, then invoke the method when the event/action happens. But like I said earlier, you should put the code in `Application#onCreate()`, and not inside a service.

Answer (score 0):

Call this metod from your MainActivity:

```
private void setNotifyAlarm() {
        long _alarm;
        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar wakeupcall = Calendar.getInstance();
        wakeupcall.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        wakeupcall.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 15);
        wakeupcall.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);

        if (wakeupcall.getTimeInMillis() <= now.getTimeInMillis())
            _alarm=wakeupcall.getTimeInMillis() + (AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY+1);
        else
            _alarm=wakeupcall.getTimeInMillis();


        al = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        notif= new Intent(this,NotifyService.class);
        fintent = PendingIntent.getService(this,0,notif,0);
        al.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,_alarm,AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, fintent);

    }
```

This method call service Every day at 15:30.
Now In your Service class:

```
@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        String time = sharedPrefs.getString("change_time", "");
    String[] parts = time.split(":");
    int chosenHour = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
    int chosenMinute = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, chosenHour);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, chosenMinute);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    Intent i = new Intent(this, SmsService.class);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, i, 0);
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 86400000, pIntent);
        return START_STICKY;
    }
```

ADD these in your Manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
<service android:name=".NotifyService" android:exported="true" android:enabled="true"/>
```